# WPF DatagridRowHeader add button for certain rows not all rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid. The datagrid is bound to a list of a custom type called Orders. Currently I have a toggle button for every row in the datagrid.

I only want a toggle button to be in the rowheader if the Orders' property MultiID (boolean) is true but can't get this to work.

In my DataGridRow I have tried using the commented out section in the line below which seems to make no difference as every row has a toggle button.

```
<Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MultiID}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource rowdetailToggleButton}"/>
            </DataTrigger>-->
        </Style.Triggers>
```

My Datagrid

```
<!-- The data grid to display orders-->
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}" 
                  x:Name="dataGridOrders" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"

                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"

                  RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetail}" 
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                                        RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dataGridOrders_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged">
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton"                                                                           
                                  Click="RowHeaderToggleButton_Click"
                                  Cursor="Hand"/>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Orders.MultiID}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="RowHeaderToggleButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

My DataGridRowHeader

```
<!-- Data Grid row with toggle button -->
    <Style x:Key="DG_RowHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGRH_Border"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightGray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>                            
                    </Border>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My DataGridRow

```
 <!-- Data grid formatting Grid Row template -->
    <Style x:Key="DG_Row" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,2,2,3"/>            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Silver"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusGood}" Value="Send">
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brushRowSend}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MultiID}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource rowdetailToggleButton}"/>
            </DataTrigger>-->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You are posting way too much code. Provide us the simplest smallest code sample that can reproduce the issue. Also, you say you "can't get this to work", it might be a good idea to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the DataTrigger in your DataTemplate you defined for your RowHeaderTemplate

```
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.MultiID,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="RowHeaderToggleButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
             </DataTrigger>
       </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: @franssu apologies I have removed some of the code and showed what I have tried. As you can probably tell I have not got my head around WPF yet.

Comment: did you try the above answer.. just put the code inside the DataTemplate you defined

Comment: sorry I didn't see the code when I was replying to the other post. Do I put this under </ControlTemplate> of my DataGridRowHeader? As when I do I get a message saying "the attachable property triggers was not found in the type DataTemplate"?

Comment: we can define Triggers in DataTemplate.. are you getting this while compiling?

Comment: sorry ignore the previous error message that was my mistake. The message I get after entering <DataTemplate> "The property value is set more than once"?

Comment: how did you set the DataTrigger?

Comment: I put the DataTemplate beneath the </ControlTemplate> section. I have edited the code in my original post so you can see what I have done.

Comment: no bro dont add there.. you already have DataTemplate defined in '<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>' .. just add this trigger code to that..

Comment: Ah I see that was pretty stupid of me. I've moved the DataTemplate now as shown in my edited code. Still the button is showing on every row. I have checked the underlying data is showing both true and false.

Comment: can you check if you are getting any binding error in output window?

Comment: Just looked in the output window and there are no BindingExpression errors

Comment: this is strange can you try updating the binding as "{Binding DataContext.MultiID,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net build-in IValueConverter itself.

Add this line into resources

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

And use it in on your button like this

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>                    
    <DataTemplate>
         <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton" 
                       Visibility="{Binding MultiID, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                       Click="RowHeaderToggleButton_Click"
                       Cursor="Hand"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: the button is still showing on every row. I have checked the underlying the data to make sure the MultID property contains both true and false values.